# Nested column names in pandas rows, trying to do an unstack type operation

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code and dataframe

```
df_initial = pd.DataFrame(data = {'ref':['02','NaN','NaN','NaN','03','NaN','NaN','NaN'], 'Part_ID':['1234-1', 'Shop_Work','repair','scrap','4567-2','Shop_Work','clean','overhaul']})
```

[image]

I wish to somehow 'unstack' rows into columns, to give the following output:

[image]

I have tried unstack but this is only for multi-index?

Comment: what should happen if the second 'Shop_Work' in the input was some other word? can you have other columns?

Comment: It's always Shop_Work

Comment: but the values 'scrap', 'clean', 'repair' etc can vary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "Part_ID" and "Shop_Work" are fixed:

```
# ensure real NaNs
df_initial = df_initial.replace('NaN', float('nan'))

# compute a mask
m = df_initial['ref'].isna()

df_out = (df_initial[~m]       # remove NaN rows
          .merge(df_initial    # merge with NaN rows
                  .ffill()[m&m.shift()]  # except first NaN row
                  .rename(columns={'Part_ID': 'Shop_Work'}),  # rename column
                 on='ref')
         )
```

output:

```
  ref Part_ID Shop_Work
0  02  1234-1    repair
1  02  1234-1     scrap
2  03  4567-2     clean
3  03  4567-2  overhaul
```

Alternatively, with two masks, in case the "Shop_Work" rows are not always first or even there:

```
# mask for NaN
m1 = df_initial['ref'].isna()
# mask for Shop_Work rows
m2 = df_initial['Part_ID'].ne('Shop_Work')

df_out = (df_initial[~m]
         .merge(df_initial
                .ffill()[m1&m2]
                .rename(columns={'Part_ID': 'Shop_Work'}),
                on='ref')
         )
```

Comment: thanks a lot mozway, works great. What's goin on with [m&m.shift()] in firstn solution and [m1&m2] in second ?

Comment: this means that a row should be True in both masks (m1 and m2). `&` is the vectorial equivalent of the python `and`. Try to print `m1`, `m2` and `m1&m2` to see for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#if NaNs are string replace to missing values
df_initial['ref'] = df_initial['ref'].replace('NaN', np.nan)

#test missing values
m = df_initial['ref'].isna()
#forward filling missing values
df_initial['ref'] = df_initial['ref'].ffill()
#new column Shop_Work
df_initial['Shop_Work'] = df_initial['Part_ID']
#replace Part_ID by mask to NaN and forward filling
df_initial['Part_ID'] = df_initial['Part_ID'].mask(m).ffill()

#get out Shop_Work rows 
df = df_initial[df_initial['Shop_Work'].ne('Shop_Work') & m].reset_index(drop=True)

print (df)
  ref Part_ID Shop_Work
0  02  1234-1    repair
1  02  1234-1     scrap
2  03  4567-2     clean
3  03  4567-2  overhaul
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with another approach using `groupby`, assuming that the first two rows of each group are always the part ID, followed by the string `'Shop_Work'`, which in turn is followed by an arbitrary number of work steps.

After replacing the `'NaN'` strings with proper `NaN` and `ffill`ing the refs to get this:

```py
  ref    Part_ID
0  02     1234-1
1  02  Shop_Work
2  02     repair
3  02      scrap
4  03     4567-2
5  03  Shop_Work
6  03      clean
7  03   overhaul
```

You can restructure each `ref` group by

```py
def restructure(frame):
    # copying the Part_ID column, skipping the first 2 rows
    frame["Shop_Work"] = frame.Part_ID.shift(-2)
    
    # dropping the two extra bottom rows resulting from the shift and
    # ffilling the Part_IDs
    return frame.dropna().replace("Shop_Work", method="ffill")
```

Result:

```py
>>> df.groupby('ref').apply(restructure).reset_index(drop=True)
  ref Part_ID Shop_Work
0  02  1234-1    repair
1  02  1234-1     scrap
2  03  4567-2     clean
3  03  4567-2  overhaul
```